# Is @angular/core 2.4.9 angular 4.0?

Tags: angular

I am moving my project form angular 1.x to a complete re write in angular 2 but according to latest release I am using angular libraries @angular/core 2.4.9. But as angular 4 is released, is angular 2.4.9 angular 4 itself, or something else is happening. I would like to start with angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2.4.9 is the most recent Angular2 version (as of 2017-03-02)
Angular 4.0.0-rc.2 is the most recent Angular4 version.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

You can create a new Angular4 project using

```
ng new foo --ng4
```

Comment: is it available on npm to download I am not able to find @angular/core rc4. Should I start building on angular2 and later upgrade?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mbostock/prereleases-and-npm-e778fc5e2420#.v6abg5984 might help